# Can Chef Sever 12 Install to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: chef-infra

I have download the package that is for Ubuntu 12.04. But currently I'm using VM of Ubuntu 14.04. Am I still able to install the Chef Server to Ubuntu 14.04?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot and let us know?

Comment: I'm still trying to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently supported. The supported platforms are as shown on the [download page](http://downloads.getchef.com/chef-server/):

1. Ubuntu 10.04
2. Ubuntu 11.04
3. Ubuntu 12.04
4. RHEL/CentOS 5
5. RHEL/CentOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 support for Chef Server 12 may be in the works since Ubuntu 14.04 is now listed on the Chef Server Prerequisites page (https://docs.getchef.com/install_server_pre.html).

However, it is still odd that Ubuntu 14.04 is not an option on the downloads page.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently installed Chef Server 12 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and could launch the Chef Management Console too (unfortunately i was stuck with some other issue so couldn't proceed further on this).

You may refer this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-chef-12-configuration-management-system-on-ubuntu-14-04-servers) for detailed steps.